# Compound Boolean Expr: Void Value Expression

Tags: ruby

```
    def success?
        return @fhosts.empty? and @khosts.empty? and @shosts.any?
    end
```

When I run that instance method, I get an error:

```
/home/fandingo/code/management/lib/ht.rb:37: void value expression
            return @fhosts.empty? and @khosts.empty? and @shosts.any?
```

I'm confused by what's happening since this works

```
    def success?
        @fhosts.empty? and @khosts.empty? and @shosts.any?
        # This also works
        # r = @fhosts.empty? and @khosts.empty? and @shosts.any?
        # return r
    end
```

I'm coming from a Python background, and I don't want anything to do with implicit returns. Programming has plenty of landmines as it is.

If we have an arbitrary expression, E, that consists of boolean operations `and` and `or` together, here are some operations we could perform:

- `if E` -- works
- `E` -- works

<strike>* `v = E` -- works</strike>

- `return E` -- broken

Why doesn't the last case work?

Edit: Actually `v = E` doesn't work. Only

v = E<sub>i</sub>

is evaluated. E<sub>i+1...k</sub> are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the very weak binding of `and` which causes it to parse out differently than you expect:

```
 return x and y
```

This actually means:

```
 (return x) and y
```

Since you're returning immediately it doesn't have a chance to evaluate the remainder of the expression.

Your version without `return` is correct:

```
x and y
```

This doesn't have a binding issue and is more idiomatic Ruby. Remember you only need to put an explicit `return` if you're trying to force an exit before the last line of the method. Being opposed to implicit returns is going to make your code look heavily non-Ruby. They're one of the reasons Ruby is so clean and simple, and how things like `a.map { |v| v * 2 }` works.

The *When in Rome* principle applies here. If you want to write Python-style Ruby you're going to be going against the grain. It's like saying "I don't like how you say X in your spoken language, so I'll just ignore that and do it my way."

This should also work:

```
return x && y
```

The `&&` method is very strongly bound so `return` is the last thing evaluated here.

Or if you really want to use `and` for whatever reason:

```
return (x and y)
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the info about binding strength. Not at all what is expected. In fact, my `v = E` example doesn't work due to this issue. Otherwise, I do write highly idiomatic Ruby, so you extended discussion on that facet is unwarranted. Re: `return` it has to be specified some times, so for consistency on a team, it should always be specified.

Comment: It's important to realize that there's an implicit `return` in Ruby and pretending there isn't can be highly problematic. Always putting an explicit return tends to produce cluttered, paranoid code. There are many Ruby style guides with varying levels of formality, but I've never seen a single one that advocates explicit returns.